# Aggregate using a certain value

Tags: r, variables, aggregate, subset, rstudio

I'm trying to use the aggregate function in R to get the mean EMISSIONS, organized by YEAR, but only for rows where FIPS is equal to 24510. The following code gives me the right result, but in addition it also adds the overall EMISSIONS, summed across all FIPS values. What am I missing here?

This is the function I'm using:

```
sum <- aggregate(NEI$Emissions, list(Year = NEI$year, NEI$fips == 24510), sum);
```

This is the output:

```
    Year    Group.2 x
1   1999    FALSE   7329692.557
2   2002    FALSE   5633326.582
3   2005    FALSE   5451611.723
4   2008    FALSE   3462343.556
5   1999    TRUE    3274.180
6   2002    TRUE    2453.916
7   2005    TRUE    3091.354
8   2008    TRUE    1862.282
```

This is the output that I would like:

```
    Year    x

1   1999    3274.180
2   2002    2453.916
3   2005    3091.354
4   2008    1862.282
```

Should I be using subset separately or can this be done with aggregate alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this sample

```
set.seed(15)
NEI <- data.frame(year=2000:2004, fips=rep(c(24510,57399), each=5), Emissions=rnorm(10))
```

you could use the command

```
mysum <- aggregate(Emissions~year, subset(NEI, fips == 24510), sum);
```

to get

```
  year  Emissions
1 2000  0.2588229
2 2001  1.8311207
3 2002 -0.3396186
4 2003  0.8971982
5 2004  0.4880163
```

(also, don't save a value to a variable named `sum` -- that will conflict with the base function `sum()`)

Comment: Epic answer - I tried it, only to get an error, but after changing my variable name it works perfectly. Thanks so much!